# How to set custom starting page number for MDBDataTable in React

Tags: reactjs, mdbreact

I have a pagination problem. MDBDataTable jumps back to first page upon data edit. Looks like, it's a bug. So, I decided to set the current page number in order to keep the current page.

```
<MDBDataTable
            data-testid='datatable'
            small
            responsive
            hover
            noBottomColumns 
            data={props.data}
            paginationLabel={['Prev', 'Next']}
            info={false} 
        />
```

Couldn't find the documentation for attribute list. Is there any attribute to set starting page, or any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  property `disableRetreatAfterSorting={true}`

I solves the problem with resetting the page. So no need to track and modify it manually

Solution was found from discussion here [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/react/control-what-the-current-page-is-for-mdbdatatable/)